# Put inline element on horizontal form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a form with form-horizontal bootstrap class.

I need to insert a text next to an input field.

Here the example, "next text" needs to be next to the input text field.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;">
  <form action="#" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="x" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="Data">Data:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input id="data" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div >next text</div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fabioravizzotti/0emj5167/1/

It's possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) with an `.input-group-addon` to do this.

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
  <div class="input-group">
     <input id="data" type="text" class="form-control" />
     <div class="input-group-addon">next text</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25msfyj5/1/).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.